# how to execute multiple sql script into flyway with same version

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, flyway

I want to execute multiple SQL file using flyway with same version.

**Solution 1**

I try multiple SQL script bind into single SQL script and execute it. But now after some days new script will come and I merge into before create SQL file. That show error. My requirement is I only execute one single SQL file and my database is going to update.

Is there any way to do that?

**Solution 2**

I try version name with timestamp but that is not satisfied ou requirement. I want only one SQL file and when I migrate then it successfully migrate SQL file as well as when I again migrate new script then it successfully migrate it but all of this process do in single script.

Is there any way to do it?

I am using FlyWay Version 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Flyway uses a history table (*flyway_schema_history*) to track which migrations were already applied. More than that, this table has a *checksum* column which is done based on the content of the migration, which means if you change it, checksum will fail and your application start also.

Maybe giving the reasons behind your choice would help to give you some light on helping you.

Comment: I have V1__version1.sql script and now i migrate it then it success full migrate now i have new script which i added last in V1__version1.sql file now i migrate it then show error because first migration object already create it. how i execute V1__version1.sql script?

Comment: is there any way to do it?? Without create a new Version file!!??

Comment: To do what you want, Flyway has a concept of Repeatable migrations.
You can check their [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/repeatable) and learn more about it.